Partial proof of existence of Navier Stokes Equations
Given an Hilbert Triple $V,H,V'$ (let's say $H^1_0,L^2,H^{-1}$), I have to prove the existence of a solution $u\in L^2(0,T;V)$ in weak form of Navier Stokes. After doing some passages i get to the following equation:
$$-\int_0^T (u_m(t),v_m)_H\phi'(t)\,dt-(u(0),v)_H\phi(0) + \eta \int_0^T (u_m(t),v_m)_V\phi'(t) dt + \int_0^T b(u_m(t),u_m(t),v_m)\phi(t)dt =\int_0^T\langle f(t),v_m\rangle _{V'}\phi(t)dt \\\forall v_m \in V_m, \forall \phi(t) \in D[0,T)$$
, which is the weak form of the Galerkin approximation written in distributional form of $$ u_t- \eta\triangle u + (u*\nabla)u + \nabla p = f$$
where $u_m$ is a subsequence (where every $u_m$ solves the respective problem in finite dimention) that converges to some u weakly in $L^2(0,T;V)$ and weakly* in $L^\infty(0,T;H)$, while $v_m$ is a subsequence which converges strongly to some $v$ in the space $V$ ($v_m$ belongs to the subspace $V_m$ generated by a Galerkin approximation.
My question is: how do i prove that $(u_m(t),v_m)_H$ converges strongly to $(u,v)_H$?

Your question would benefit from more information. For one thing, I recommend filling in the $\ldots$ terms in your weak PDE, since they may be relevant to solving the problem.

Also, what is your definition of weak solution, and what space does $\phi$ belong to?

Finally, this might be more of a wording issue, but you say $u_m$ converges to a weak solution. Since you are trying to prove existence of a weak solution, presumably you don't know yet whether it exists. Perhaps you mean to say that you know $u_m$ converges to some limit $u$, and your goal is now to show $u$ is a weak solution?

thank you for the suggestions. My definition of weak solution is that , given $u, u_m \in X$, then $\forall L \in X'$ i have $L(u_m) \to L(u)$, similarly for weakly* convergence. Also, $\phi \in D[0,T)$, which is the set of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support in [0,T).

That's the definition of weak-convergence not the one of a weak solution
